# Sitecore Download Package

Tags: package, sitecore

I created a package for items in Sitecore, but forgot downloading the package in wizard.

Is there any way to download the package I created??

Many items have been changed, so creating the package again is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be in your data folder under the /packages directory.

If you haven't got access to the sever directly you can download the file using the File explorer.

More info here

https://superruub.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/sitecore-package-designer-zipfile-location-folder/

Answer (score 6):

A little old, but from within sitecore:

1. Start the installation wizard,
2. Click browse
3. Find the package (UI sucks, not sorting or anything)
4. Click download

From the sitecore file explorer, I couldn't go all the way the data folder (outside the website folder)

Answer (score 0):

The pacakage will be in your “~/Data/packages” folder.